# Can't push a git repo on a local server

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013

I have a local Git server set up on my network, but I'm having issues committing my project code to it.

**Here are the steps I've tried so far:**

- Using visual studio 2013 a create a new project.  Then while still inside the IDE I right click on my solution in the solution explorer and I add the solution to source control.  For the source control type I use 'Git' as that's what type my local server is.  I create this project on my local server machine which is at address 192.168.0.1
- Once everything is set up, I commit the project into my source control system and push the changes.
- I then close the solution that I've just committed, and close visual studio.
- I then move to a different machine (Where I want to work on my project) open visual studio 2013, open Team explorer and clone the project that I just created in previous steps.
- I use the following settings to clone this new project:

  *Git repo to clone : 192.168.0.1/GitTest/Test1*

  *Where to clone : C:/Users/Me/Desktop/GitTest/*

Once I click on the clone button, everything works as I expect, the solution is created on the new machine, the files I initially created and everything looks ok.

The previously cloned project opens fine in visual studio and I see exactly what I expect to see in my solution explorer.

- My next step is to add some code to the project, I do this in the usual manner of adding new items and typing in some code, then saving it.
- Once I have some code to commit, I go back into the Team Explorer, I find my list of changes and a click on the required buttons to commit them.

It's at this point where things start to fail.

In Un-Synced commits section I click on the button labeled **push** and I'm immediately presented with an error message stating the following:

**An error occurred. Detailed message: An error was raised by libgit2. Category = Unknown (Error). No error message has been provided by the native library.**

I have no idea what this error means or how to fix it, has anyone here come across this error before, or even a similar situation which they've been able to fix, if so could anyone tell me how they managed to get things working.

Many Thanks in advance if you can.

Comment: You're trying to push changes from the original repository to a clone on another machine? Does pulling from the original repo work when working on the cloned repo?

Comment: I try to push changes from the cloned repo. I just tried to pull from the cloned repo and it works. But then if I add code, commit, and Push from the cloned, I have the same error when trying to push... So I can pull, but I can't push.

Comment: @bobby4078 could you try from the command line, after installed a Git For windows? (http://msysgit.github.io/)

Comment: I got this:$ git push
fatal: '\192.168.0.1\GitTest\Test7' does not appear to be a git repository

Warning: Your console font probably doesn't support Unicode. If you experience strange characters in the output, consider switching to a TrueType font such as Lucida Console!
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

Comment: Hi there.
How to you clone? using https? if so the repo might have read only permissions

Comment: I cloned using visual studio 2013, and the address was on a local server : \\192.168.0.1\...

Comment: Then try pushing in command line to \\192.168.0.1\GitTest\Test7

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pushing to non-bare repositories (repositories that contain working trees with actual file contents) is considered bad practise. Instead you should create a central bare repository to and from which you push and pull changes from each individual dev repository.

You can create a bare Git repository using `git init --bare`. Then just set the bare repo as a remote for a dev repository.

For non-bare repositories only pulling is an option. You could `push -f`, but be sure to verify forced changeset pushing with your fellow developers who might be working on the same repositories.

If you want, you can also create a hosted bare repository to Github, Bitbucket and the like.

Comment: Although you are correct, this doesn't really answer his question.

Comment: Actually this answer my question, I've used git --bare init and it is now working, I can push in visual studio! Thanks.

Comment: Did you update the remote in your development repository to reference the new `bare` repository?

Answer (score 2):

At your git project repo, modify .git\config file content,  change `bare = false` to `bare = true`.

[image: git repo config file content]